# how to set laravel nullable function parameter

Tags: laravel

i am working on laravel ecommerce project, and in the function that gets the products i need to send parameter of the brand i need to show the products of, and if i didn't send any params it returns all the products

the function

```
public function index($brand)
{
    if ($brand) {
        $products = Product::where('brand_id', '=', $brand)->get();

        return response()->json($products);
    } else {
        $products = Product::get();

        return response()->json($products);
    }
}
```

the route

```
Route::get('/products/{brand}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiProductController@index');
```

when i try the URL in postman and write specific brand it returns the products successfully but when i doesn't it return nothing instead of all the products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply declare the parameter as null.. so when you will pass the parameter it will get the passed value, otherwise it will be null.

```
public function index($brand = null)
{
    if ($brand) {
        $products = Product::where('brand_id', '=', $brand)->get();

        return response()->json($products);
    } else {
        $products = Product::get();

        return response()->json($products);
    }
}
```

and then make the parameter optional in the route definition as well

```
Route::get('/products/{brand?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiProductController@index');
```

now this should work as you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have defaulted to the route with the parameter!..

```
Route::get('/products/{brand?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiProductController@index');
```

adding '?' help laravel can understand it

Comment: i make it and now there is an error, how to solve it?

Comment: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ApiProductController::index(), 0 passed

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like,

```php
public function index($brand = null)
{
    $products = Product::when($brand, function ($query, $brand) {
        return $query->where('brand_id', $brand);
    })
    ->get();
    
    return response()->json($products);
}
```